# Compute $\iiint_R 6z \ dV.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Integrate the function $$f(x,y,z)=6z$$ over the tetrahedral
>   $$R=\{(x,y,z):x\geq0, \ y\geq 0, \ z\geq 0, \ 5x+y+z \leq 5\}.$$

This tetrahedral can obtain hegiths in $z$-axis from 0 to 5 in the first octant. Drawing this out, I get that the bounds are

\begin{array}{lcl}
0 \leq x \leq  1 \\
0 \leq y \leq 5-5x \\
0 \leq z \leq -5x-y+5
\end{array}

So

$$\iiint_R 6z \ dV=\int_0^1\int_0^{5-5x}\int_0^{-5x-y+5}6z \ dzdydx=\frac{125}{4}.$$

Can anyone confirm this is correct and check for any improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems absolutely correct as set up and also as calculation.

To check the result note that the given integral is equal to

$$6 \cdot z_G \cdot V=6 \cdot \frac54 \cdot \frac{25}{6}=\frac{125}{4}$$

indeed for geometric properties of tetrahedron  the centroid is at $\frac{H}{4}$ and volume is $\frac{A\cdot H}{3}$.

Comment: Who, foolish and stupid person, want to delete my beautiful and brilliant answer?

Comment: I dont understand. what is $z_G$ anv $V$ in this case?

Comment: $z_G$ is the z coordinate of the centroid of the tetrahedron which is given by $$z_G=\frac{\iiint z\,dV}{V}$$ thus $$\iiint 6z\,dV=6 z_G V$$ It is a good way to check in this case.

Comment: Ah now I see. Thanks gimusi!

Comment: When possible it is important have different methods to check otherwise that repeat the same calculation of the integral twice.

Comment: This was a very clever check indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct.\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \int_0^{5-5x} \int_0^{-5x-y+5} 6z \,\,\, dz dy dx \\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^{5-5x}  3(-5x-y+5)^2 \,\,dy dx \\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^{5-5x}  3(5x+y-5)^2 \,\,dy dx \\
&=\int_0^1   -(5x+0-5)^3 \, dx \\
&=-5^3 \int_0^1(x-1)^3 \, dx \\
&= -5^3 \frac{(x-1)^4\mid_0^1}{4}\\
&=\frac{125}{4}
\end{align}